# run "gclient" command in cmd.exe, show "cipd lock is held trying again after delay"

Tags: chromium

I want to download Chromium source code but according to the official document: download "depot_tools" and add its path to the environment variable "PATH". After running "gclient" commmand in cmd.exe, it shows the below message:

```
"Bootstrapping cipd client for windows-386 from https://chrome-infra-packages.ap
pspot.com/client?platform=windows-386&version=git_revision:d2677a4477e59cb7de00
f1fb8a00e96b1aaeb927..."
```

and wait a few seconds show "CIPD lock is held, trying again after delay..."
in "chromium / chromium / tools / depot_tools / master / . / cipd.ps1" have the code:

```
while ($true) 
{
   $cipd_lock_file = $false
   try {
   $cipd_lock_file = [IO.File]::OpenWrite($cipd_lock)

   if (!(Test-Path $client)) {
      echo "Bootstrapping cipd client for $plat-$arch from $url..."

      $wc = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient)
      $wc.Headers.add('User-Agent', $user_agent)
      $wc.DownloadFile($url, $client)
    }
    break
    } catch {
        echo "CIPD lock is held, trying again after delay..."
        Start-Sleep -s 1
    } finally {
    if ($cipd_lock_file) {
       $cipd_lock_file.close()
    }
  }
}
```

but I can't understand it. My OS is windows 7 64-bit. Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean gclient sync?

Comment: no "gclient sync"。the offical document said: "From a cmd.exe shell, run the command gclient (without arguments).On first run, gclient will install all the Windows-specific bits needed to work with the code, including msysgit and python.". it should install git and python, then check out the chrome code.

Comment: Chromium developer here. depot_tools will install python and other build tools. You should follow the instructions on this page: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

Comment: ok.i work with vs2015 and guess this lead to this problem.i install vs2017 then try again.thank you

Comment: The latest version of Chromium builds will try to use VS 2017. What version of Chromium are you targeting?